# Can't prove an equation using induction

Tags: induction

I have an equation
$$
\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{2^2} + \frac{3}{2^3} + \cdots + \frac{n}{2^n} = 2 - \frac{n + 2}{2^n}
$$

Below is what I have already done:
$$
\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{2^2} + \frac{3}{2^3} + \cdots + \frac{n}{2^n} + \frac{n + 1}{2^{n+1}} = 2 - \frac{n + 2}{2^n} + \frac{n + 1}{2^{n+1}}=
2 - \frac{3n + 5}{2^{n + 1}} 
$$

I want the right part of the equation to be transformed to $$ 2-\frac{n + 1 + 2}{2^{n+1}}$$
Maybe do I do something wrong? I will be appreciated for any help.

Comment: Be careful with + and - sign: the numerator is not $3n+5$ but $n+3$.

Comment: You made a mistake in the calculation of the fraction $\frac{3n+5}{2^{n+1}}$.

Comment: Oh yes, I see. Thank you very much for your help :-)

Comment: Do you need to prove by induction? Because this is a [Arithmetico-Geometric Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence), with known summation expression.

Comment: @Mefitico that's an exercise from a book

Comment: The method of proof you're trying is not the best way to go about it. Only work on one side of the equation. You've effectively applied the induction hypothesis to both sides. This will of course yield a true equally but is not very useful

Comment: @N8tron Ok, I got you. Thank you for your remark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot about the negative sign:
$$
-\frac{n+2}{2^{n}}+\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{-(2n+4)+n+1}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{-n-3}{2^{n+1}}=-\frac{(n+1)+2}{2^{n+1}}.
$$